# Error creating bean Mvc Mysql Hibernate Spring

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, javabeans

I try to create a Maven progect with spring framework and FreeMarker. Also I create some Entity and a connection DB and a View. I start Tomcat for see the result, if this app is working. And I've got an error and can't solve it! When I statrt Tomcat I've got "HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error".

This is a Config Class

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="Name.Controller")
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
//@PropretySource("classpath:database.propreties")
public class AppConfig {
@Bean
public FreeMarkerViewResolver configResoler() {
    FreeMarkerViewResolver resolver= new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("");
    resolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
    resolver.setCache(true);
    return resolver;
}
@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer configurerFM() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer config= new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    config.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/view/");

    return config;
}
@Bean

public DataSource getDataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource db= new DriverManagerDataSource();
    db.setUsername("root");
    db.setPassword("root");
    db.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver"); // was com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    db.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Java");
    return db;
}
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactory(){
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter=new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory= new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan(getClass().getPackage().getName());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager(){
   // JpaTransactionManager jtm= new JpaTransactionManager(getEntityManager().getObject());
    return new JpaTransactionManager(getEntityManagerFactory().getObject());

}
```

I've got a Maven dependency into pom file for MySql:

```
   <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.30.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.26</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

In file pom I've got 2 Drivers, one for MariaDB and one for MySql. It's just because I try to understand if the problem was there, but I'm using MySql not MariaDB

How may I solve it? Thank you

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getEntityManagerFactory' defined in AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime not present
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1153)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:578)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1143)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5264)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1783)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:460)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:408)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
    Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime not present
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:95)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:1205)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.extractAttributeConverterParameterizedType(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.<init>(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:124)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.from(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.from(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.applyScanResultsToManagedResources(ScanningCoordinator.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:82)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:168)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:52)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
        ... 62 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1407)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:466)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
        ... 86 more
05-Sep-2021 23:39:10.297 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/untitled_war] threw load() exception
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1407)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:466)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:95)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:1205)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.extractAttributeConverterParameterizedType(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.<init>(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:124)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.from(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.from(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.applyScanResultsToManagedResources(ScanningCoordinator.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:82)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:168)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I can't see the h2 database dependency in your maven setup, add this:</strike>

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.200</version>
</dependency>
```

If you want to use MySQL, why is your datasource driver class name being declared as h2 in the first place? change it to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

```
db.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
```

Comment: at first time it was "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", but it doesn't work. So Itry with "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver", and after I find on web this one "org.h2.Driver". So I try 3 Drivers.

Comment: Show us the exception when you change it to mysql

Comment: `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is deprecated since mysql 8

Comment: SEVERE: Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getEntityManagerFactory' defined in AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime not present
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
 it's also the same error. It's just writing that com.mysql.jdbc.Driver it's deprecated

Comment: in fact I used this one "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" because it was recommanded

Comment: man please add the whole exception when you're using `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` to your post

Comment: done. But the stack trace it's too long, I can't post it all

Comment: You have a missing dependency -
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
    <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.2</version>
</dependency>
`

Comment: oh it's working. Does't give me more error "500-Internal Server Error". Thank you!

Comment: Great! maybe mark the answer as correct if it helped out.